# When exactly is Angular Universal sent to the client?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I just stated to learn Angular Universal and can't understand one thing.

For example I have a component where I get tasks and display them

```
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.tasksService.getAll().subscribe(tasks => this.tasks = tasks);
}
....
```

When is this component will be sent to the client? Does the server send the main template and afterward the query is being executed on the client, and this client displays the fetched todos? Or server waits for the request is being completed and after that composes the template and sends to the client?

Which one of the behaviours I described above is performed and is there any possibility to change it?

Comment: Angular Universal will completely render any component you to apply SSR to. That means any service calls, etc, will all be executed server-side so that a completely rendered component can be sent as the response. Once that initial response is served, Angular takes over on the client-side.

Comment: @Brandon it there a way to change this behavior in certain paces? E.g. I want a pagination for the comments (infinite scroll or button "Show more") - here I need my front-end to call the API and change the DOM on his own.

Comment: That should be handled-client side automatically. Only the initial render of the component is handled server-side. Any click events for example would be client-side.

Comment: @Brandon thanks, you've answered my question

Comment: You’re welcome. Always glad to help.